# canvas drawImage loop issue

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to modify [this](https://github.com/dwmkerr/spaceinvaders) canvas game by replacing fillRect with images.

No problems when changing the ship code in *spaceinvaders.js* on line 529:

```
ship = new Image();
ship.src = "images/ship.svg";

ctx.drawImage(ship, this.ship.x - (this.ship.width / 2), this.ship.y - (this.ship.height / 2), this.ship.width, this.ship.height);
```

but having trouble with invaders loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {

    var invader = this.invaders[i] = new Image();
    this.invaders[i].src = "images/space_invader.png";

    //ctx.fillRect(invader.x - invader.width/2, invader.y - invader.height/2, invader.width, invader.height);

    this.invaders[i].onload = function(){

        var thisX = invader.x * 18;
        var thisY = invader.y * 14;

        return function() {
            ctx.drawImage(invader,invader.x - invader.width/2, invader.y - invader.height/2, invader.width, invader.height);
            //ctx.drawImage(this, thisX, thisY, invader.width, invader.height);
        };

    };
}
```

When I get the invader image to finally show, it stacks them all in top of each other. - Even with thisX and thisY variables.

EDIT:

```
img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){

    for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<this.invaders.length; j++) {
            var invader = this.invaders[i];
            ctx.drawImage(img,j*18, i*14, invader.width, invader.height);
        }
    }
}

img.src = "images/space_invader.png";
```

Gives: cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

EDIT 2:

```
img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){

    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<10; j++) {
            ctx.drawImage(img,j*22, i*16, 18, 14);
        }
    }
}

img.src = "images/space_invader.png";
```

This way I'm atleast able to see invaders but they are static: [image]

EDIT 3:

```
var invaders=[{x:0,y:0},{x:20,y:0},{x:40,y:0},{x:60,y:0},{x:80,y:0},{x:100,y:0},{x:120,y:0},{x:140,y:0},{x:160,y:0},{x:180,y:0},{x:0,y:16},{x:20,y:16},{x:40,y:16},{x:60,y:16},{x:80,y:16},{x:100,y:16},{x:120,y:16},{x:140,y:16},{x:160,y:16},{x:180,y:16},{x:200,y:16},{x:0,y:32},{x:20,y:32},{x:40,y:32},{x:60,y:32},{x:80,y:32},{x:100,y:32},{x:120,y:32},{x:140,y:32},{x:160,y:32},{x:180,y:32},{x:200,y:32},{x:0,y:48},{x:20,y:48},{x:40,y:48},{x:60,y:48},{x:80,y:48},{x:100,y:48},{x:120,y:48},{x:140,y:48},{x:160,y:48},{x:180,y:48},{x:200,y:48},{x:0,y:64},{x:20,y:64},{x:40,y:64},{x:60,y:64},{x:80,y:64},{x:100,y:64},{x:120,y:64},{x:140,y:64},{x:160,y:64},{x:180,y:64},{x:200,y:64}];

for (var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {

    invaders[i] = new Image();

    invaders[i].onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, x, y);         
    };

    invaders[i].src = "images/space_invader.png";
}
```

Gives x is not defined.

EDIT 4:

```
function createImage(i){   

var image = new Image();  
    image.src = "images/space_invader.png";
    image.onload = function(){  
        ctx.drawImage(image,imagePos[i][0],imagePos[i][1], 20, 16);
    } 
}

var imagePos=[[0,0],[20,0],[40,0],[60,0],[80,0],[100,0],[120,0],[140,0],[160,0],[180,0],[0,16],[20,16],[40,16],[60,16],[80,16],[100,16],[120,16],[140,16],[160,16],[180,16],[0,32],[20,32],[40,32],[60,32],[80,32],[100,32],[120,32],[140,32],[160,32],[180,32],[0,48],[20,48],[40,48],[60,48],[80,48],[100,48],[120,48],[140,48],[160,48],[180,48],[0,64],[20,64],[40,64],[60,64],[80,64],[100,64],[120,64],[140,64],[160,64],[180,64]];

for(var i = 0; i <this.invaders.length; i += 1){
    createImage(i); 
}
return
```

Shows invaders but they keep flickering. (main game loop?)

Comment: You overwrite invaders with your instance of Image. Use a local variable like `var invader = new Image()` and then use `invaders[i].x` to get the coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### One variable can only hold one value.

There is a simple rule that will help you avoid problems like this. Never declare functions inside loops.

**Why??**

Let look at a loop

```
var imagePos = [[10,10],[10,20],[10,30],[10,40],[10,50],[20,10],[20,20],[20,30],[20,40],[20,50]];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "imagename";
    image.onload = function(){
         ctx.drawImage(image,imagePos[i][0],imagePos[i][1]);
    } 
}
// end
return
```

You are expecting 10 images to start to load, when each image has loaded you expect them to be draw at the correct position. But that will never happen.

The `onload` function will not fire until the for loop has completed and the execution has returned. You have 2 variables, `i` and `image`, by the time the first onload event fires `i = 10` and it will stay that way for each onload. Also the image you referance inside the onload function is also only one variable and can not hold more than one image. Even though each `onload` is correctly bound to the image, the `image` variable will be pointing to the last images created in the loop.

You are kind of expecting `i` and `image` to hold 10 separate values each and know what needs what value when.

The correct way to do that is as follows

```
function createImage(i){   // load an image function 
                           // creates a new i each time it is called
    var image = new Image();  // create a new image variable 
    image.src = "imagename";
    image.onload = function(){  // now the onload will have the correct variables 
         ctx.drawImage(image,imagePos[i][0],imagePos[i][1]);
    } 
 }
var imagePos = [[10,10],[10,20],[10,30],[10,40],[10,50],[20,10],[20,20],[20,30],[20,40],[20,50]];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1){
    createImage(i); // call the function so it can create unique variables for each image
}
// end
return
```

You could also have done it with the function inside the loop but you would have needed to use the functions bound object to store the values you wanted.

```
var imagePos = [[10,10],[10,20],[10,30],[10,40],[10,50],[20,10],[20,20],[20,30],[20,40],[20,50]];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "imagename";
    image.posIndex = i; // attach the index to the image
    image.onload = function(){ // instead of using image use the image bound to the function 
                                // and referenced via the this token
         ctx.drawImage(this, imagePos[this.posIndex][0], imagePos[this.posIndex][1]);
    } 
    
}
// end
return
```

The is nothing wrong with doing it this way, apart from the trap you found. That is why the general rule is, if you are unfamiliar with javascript, do not declare functions inside loops.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But this particular canvas game is proving to be too much of headache. Flickering images, images not appearing in FF, etc that I feel it's easier to start from scratch. -- Replace fillRects with images, it will be easy they said! : )

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use the x and y properties of the Image object. First it's read only and second it's probably not set and there for always 0 since you are creating a new Image instance.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Okay, any examples of Image object loops?

Comment: Can you show me the code including the setup of `this.invaders` as well?

Comment: All I've added was the for cycle in line 533 under // Draw invaders. Everything else in spaceinvaders.js is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

Great! Now all you need is some kind of game loop to get them moving. I would move the x and y positions (from your current for loop) into individual objects so you can modify each invader per (update) loop.

`var invaders = [
    {x: 100, y: 100, speed: 10},
    {x: 140, y: 100, speed: 10},
    {x: 180, y: 100, speed: 10},
    // and so on
];`

Try reading more information regarding game loops and how they work here: https://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing

edit: Something like this...

```
for(var i = 0; i < invaders.length; i++) {

    var invader = new Image();

    invader.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, invaders[i].x, invaders[i].y);         
    };

    invaders[i].src = "images/space_invader.png";
}
```

Comment: Gives no errors but shows no ships. I can still see them firing.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the height and width again? Wasn't able to test the snippet tbh.

Comment: Tried that, no effect.

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: As you already wrote in the other comment I would start over using a canvas game tutorial or an existing framework which makes your life way easier! Good luck :)